# Bash: env in rustup node module not found after logging in

Tags: bash, environment-variables, node.js

I've used Rustup and Cargo for a Node project, and now I don't need them anymore, so tried removing both. However, each time I connect to the Raspberry Pi in question via SSH, I get this output:

```
~ $ ssh 192.168.0.2
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.76-v7+ #1597 SMP Fri Nov 4 10:13:17 GMT 2022 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sat Nov 19 08:04:39 2022 from 192.168.0.132

-bash: /home/pixelcode/project/node_modules/rustup/CARGO_HOME/env: File or directory not found
-bash: /home/pixelcode/project/node_modules/rustup/CARGO_HOME/env: File or directory not found

pixelcode@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Note that the directory does indeed not exist anymore since I don't need it (anymore).

Why does the system still try to access that directory and how can I stop it from doing so? The directory not set as an environment variable.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have anything in the raspberry account's `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file that refers to the non-existing file?

Comment: The `.bashrc` indeed contained a reference to the path in question which I removed. There are also references to `usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` and `/home/.nvm/bash_completion` but they don't contain that path. The `.bash_profile` file isn't present on my system.

Removing that path made one of the two identical `file not found` errors, but the other one remains.